# I want to use CONCAT and exclude and duplicate any duplicate entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I'm trying to use the CONCAT expression, but also exclude any duplicate entries.

So I'm trying to update a report based on a single process held in our product. The problem is that whoever created the tables that the current report is pulling from is not from a single table. Currently I have found three tables that the report pulls from for one column.

```
SELECT concat(dbo.t_log_TaskBody.TaskDescription,' ', dbo.t_ezDocument.FileName) as Title

FROM dbo.t_logs_SigDocPrintedEmailed

LEFT JOIN dbo.t_log_Data ON t_logs_SigDocPrintedEmailed.t_ezDataPKid = dbo.t_log_Data.PKid

LEFT JOIN dbo.t_log_TaskBody ON dbo.t_logs_SigDocPrintedEmailed.t_ezSignDocumentQ_PKid = dbo.t_log_TaskBody.DocumentId

LEFT JOIN dbo.t_ezSignDocumentQ ON dbo.t_logs_SigDocPrintedEmailed.t_ezSignDocumentQ_PKid = dbo.t_ezSignDocumentQ.PKid

LEFT JOIN dbo.t_ezArcSigDocQLog ON dbo.t_logs_SigDocPrintedEmailed.t_ezSignDocumentQ_PKid = dbo.t_ezArcSigDocQLog.t_ezSignDocQPKID

LEFT JOIN dbo.t_ezDocument ON dbo.t_ezSignDocumentQ.t_ezDocument = dbo.t_ezDocument.PKID or dbo.t_ezArcSigDocQLog.t_ezDocument = EasyID.dbo.t_ezDocument.PKID
```

So now that I have one entry that happens to connect to two of the tables I'm pulling from to get a title of a document I end up with the title appearing twice in one box. Is there anyway I can use CONCAT to combine the two tables while keeping it to unique entries, or is there a better way of doing this.

I'll get Something along the lines of:

- Title
- null
- Title Title
- null
- Title
- Title

Comment: I'm guessing this is SQL Server, but you should edit your question and add the appropriate RDBMS tag

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just insert the keyword DISTINCT after SELECT?

Comment: No but that doesn't seem to have any effect on the title. I don't know if it's due to it being wrapped in parentheses so it's looked at as one piece rather than two different pieces.

Comment: Thank you all for the help I ended up fixing it by replacing the concat with an isnull equation. I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample results, I think you want `COALESCE()`, not `CONCAT()`:

```
concat(dbo.t_log_TaskBody.TaskDescription, dbo.t_ezDocument.FileName) as Title
```

You have no examples where results are actually concatenated.